# Openlayers creating RegularPolygon that is too small then return false

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

My project has to use imagelayer to show map , it can create box on map, box will be a area to put device marker on top , but when the box is 
  too small , there will be a bug in project..., so is there some one who can tell me how to prevent this from happening?

The code is below:

```
// map init
$map = new OpenLayers.Map("gmap");
$map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

//add basic layer
$map.addLayers([new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
    'Main Layer',
    'images/ec/area/area1.jpg',
    new OpenLayers.Bounds(0, 0, 2565, 1293),
    new OpenLayers.Size(1282.5, 646.5),
    {layers: 'basic'}
)]);

//add vector Layer to map
vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");//Area layer
vectorLayer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay1");//device layer
$map.addLayers([vectorLayer,vectorLayer1]);

selectControl = {
    selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([vectorLayer,vectorLayer1], {
        onSelect: createPopup,
        onUnselect: destroyPopup
    }),
    box : new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectorLayer,
        OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
            handlerOptions: {
                sides: 4,
                irregular: true
            },
            callbacks: {
                up: function(geometry){

                    if( geometry.getArea() < 2500 ){
                        alert("Box too small can not be create!");
                        return false; //still can not return false!!!!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
};

//this can log Area Size But can not return false!!
selectControl["box"].handler.callbacks.create = function(data) {
    if(data.getArea() < 2500){
        console.log("Area Size:"+data.getArea());
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

[image: screen shot is hre]

Should I check when the box too small then remove it?

Or how to prevent the create box when the box is too small?

Comment: Exactly WHAT is teh bug?? It will help to know ..

Comment: box will be a area to put device marker on top , but when the box is too small , there will be a bug in project...

Comment: Ok, WHAT is the bug, please post a screen shot ro something to describe what the `Bug` actually is ..

Comment: sorry for i do not use this post... thanks all expert.....

Comment: Probably you have a conflict in the SRS between the data layer and the Vector Layer you are drawing the Box on .. What is the EPSG of the base layer .. try making them the same ..

Comment: You want the done callback, which receives a geometry, not an up callback, which receives an event.

Answer (score 1):

My friend Chris help me to resolve the problem and the answer will be like this:   http://jsfiddle.net/v18kuxgf/

```
polygonLayer.events.register('featureadded', null, function(event) {
                        var feature = event.feature,
                            geometry = feature.geometry;
                        if (geometry.getArea() < 2500) {
                            alert('Box too small to create!');
                            polygonLayer.removeFeatures(feature);
                        }
                    });
```